# What is the equivalent of `Graphics2d.getFontMetrics()` in Codename one?

Tags: fonts, truetype, codenameone

I'm looking for a way to programatically find the ascent and descent values of the current (truetype) font in Codename one. The codename one `Graphics` class doesn't have a `getFontMetrics()` method.

Text width can be determined by using `Graphics.stringWidth(text)`, height can be queried from the `Font` object. But there doesn't seem to be a way to determine ascent and descent values.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ascent/descent values were very hard to codify across platforms so we codified that into a single height value which includes the entire height.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to align texts with different fonts vertically? I want to render formulas with indices and exponents. I think as a workaround I could provide factors (i.e. ascent is 70% of height for font A and 75% for font B) and calcuate more or less accurate values for the selected font size myself. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Check out http://www.codenameone.com/featured-yhomework.html what he did was use specific TTF fonts and he could then tune everything based on his knowledge of the font in question. 
We didn't implement styled text components so we didn't have a real need for proper baseline behavior and features like that yet but I'm guessing that this is something we will add some day.

Comment: Ok, I will accept this answer. What I ended up with in the end is extracting the ascent/descent values from the font in a swing app, and storing the values for the font in some kind of wrapper class I use in CN1 and then scaling these values with the font height. (I have to use a wrapper anyway because the code shall run on swing and CN1).